# I have created a dynamic checkbox using php, but when i use .checked() to check it, only first radio button is checked. how to check the rest?

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<div  id="pop2" class="box2" style="display: none">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="second" style="margin-top:3px;margin-left:10px;font-size:100%">Add to</div>
<?php 
    $new2=array();
    $new2=getlist();
    foreach($new2 as $value){ 
        echo'<input type="radio" id="qwerty" name="qwerty" value="'.$value.'" onclick="theLast()"  />';

        echo"$value";echo"<br>";}
?>
        <hr>
        <button type="button" id="add2" class="new" onclick="theFinal()" >Create new list</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

and i used javascript to check in theLast() function

```
  if (document.getElementById('qwerty').checked) {
      window.lists=document.getElementById('qwerty').value;
  }
```

only first radio button is working fine, rest are not detected in .checked()

Answer (score 1):

Having the same `id` attribute for all the checkboxes can cause these kinds of issues. I would suggest using a commom class instead and iterating the checkboxes using the [getElementByClassName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) function to check for "checked" boxes.

Comment: I added class in place of id in echo statement. and changed to getElementByClassName

Comment: ok. I'm not certain I understand what you are trying to do with your code but it looks like u want to be able to generate a list of the selected checkboxes, is that correct? if so, u can simply iterate over the selected classes in `theFinal` function like so: `var x = document.getElementsByClassName("yourClassName");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    console.log(x[i].value + ' is selected')
}`